# Como puedo rellenar una matriz con un arreglo ya existente?

Tags: java, array, matrices

Tengo que crear un algoritmo que simule el juego de las 21 cartas mostrando al usuario una matriz de 3 X 7 con caracteres aleatorios simulando las cartas del truco

Estos caracteres no se deben repetir y finalmente en un bucle crear un menú para que el usuario indique  en que columna se encuentra su carta y así proceder hasta encontrarla

Mi problema es que al querer cargar los caracteres ya generados en el arreglo mas grande para pasarlo a la matriz y o no los carga o simplemente el programa ni compila..

Pd: El enunciado posee como requisito usar las variables constantes del inicio se pueden declarar mas variables pero no es la idea

Adjunto el Código a continuación :

```
  import java.util.Random;

public class Proyecto_2 {
   
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //Constantes para estandarizar los valores del programa
        final short Max_Tarjetas_Grupo = 7;//Tarjetas del grupo
        final short Max_Grupos = 3;//Cantidad de Grupos
        final short Max_Tarjetas = (Max_Tarjetas_Grupo*Max_Grupos)+1;//Total de tarjetas
        final short Min_Tarjeta_Valor = 'A';//Tarjeta inicial en este caso letra A
       final short Max_Tarjeta_Valor= (char)(Max_Tarjetas+(int)('A')-1); //Tarjeta final.
        
        //Variable para generar los numeros aleatorios
            Random generador =  new Random();
            int j=0,numero,tope=Max_Tarjetas_Grupo;

        //Varibles que deben usarse para resolver el problema 
        char[] grupo1 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo],//7
               grupo2 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo],//7
               grupo3 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo];//7
               
        char[] deck = new char [Max_Tarjetas];

     



       for(int i=1;i<deck.length;i++){
            
            numero = (generador.nextInt((int)Max_Tarjeta_Valor-(int)Min_Tarjeta_Valor)+1+(int)(Min_Tarjeta_Valor));
             
           //Obtencion de numeros sin repetir 
            while(j<i){
                if(deck[j]==numero){
                    j=0;
                    
                    numero = (generador.nextInt((int)Max_Tarjeta_Valor-(int)Min_Tarjeta_Valor)+1+(int)(Min_Tarjeta_Valor));
                    
                }
                else{
                    j++;
                }
            }
            deck[i] = (char)numero; 
        }   
        for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
            grupo1[k] = deck[0];
            
            grupo2[k] = deck[7];
           
            grupo3[k] = deck[14];
        
            System.out.print(grupo1[k]);
            System.out.print(grupo2[k]);
            System.out.print(grupo3[k]);
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tu arreglo deck antes del ultimo for tiene 22 valores,pero recuerda que en un arreglo las posciciones empiezan desde 0 por ende solo tienes 21 posiciones y tu estas intentanto imprimir la posicion 22 (error).En el ultimo for pones k<deck.length pero tus grupos nuevamente tienen 7 valores cada uno y 6 posiciones y al poner k<deck.length estas diciendo que el ciclo se repita 21 veces

Comment: Entonces para poder rellenar mis arreglos de 7 posiciones debo iterarlo de otra manara o simplemente cambiar mi planteo
Porque me conflictúa el echo de que no pueda llenar la dichosa matriz

Comment: No entendí bien tu pregunta pero el error es evidente, en ** for(int k=0;k<deck.length;k++)** el valo de k recorre desde 0 hasta 21 y tus arreglos grupo1, grupo2 y grupos3 declaraste con una longitud de 7

Comment: Ahi modifique un poco el codigo y creo que es mas entendible lo que quiero lograr con el mismo Quiero usar los 21 caractes del arreglo deck para rellenar a los arreglos de los grupos que son de 7 cada uno para formar asi una arreglo de 3 columnas y 7 filas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en el ejercicio que quieres realizar, te recomendaría usar una matriz de [7][3] se podría insertar los valores en filas y columnas con dos for, sin embargo eso te generaría valores repetidos usando Random(), lo cual no es lo ideal para el juego, aun así puedes generar valores aleatorios en cada fila y trabajarlos como arreglos unidimensionales y después unirlos en una sola matriz. Algo así

```
 int [] baraja1=new Random().ints(1, 7).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja2=new Random().ints(8, 15).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja3=new Random().ints(16, 23).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja4=new Random().ints(24, 31).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja5=new Random().ints(32, 39).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja6=new Random().ints(40, 47).distinct().limit(3).toArray();
    int [] baraja7=new Random().ints(48, 52).distinct().limit(3).toArray();

    int baraja[][]={baraja1,baraja2,baraja3,baraja4,baraja5,baraja6,baraja7};
```

como son 52 cartas de la cuales solo escogeremos 21, estas pueden generarse aleatoriamente cada vez que inicies el programa, sin repetirse en la matriz, y una vez tengas tu matriz trabajar en los siguientes pasos.Y para imprimir la matriz seria de la siguiente manera_:

```
static void mostrarCartas(int[][] cartas) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++) {
              System.out.print("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < cartas[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(cartas[i][j] + "\t"+"|");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

[image: Salida]

Comment: esta seria la versión final del juego https://github.com/Dramaturgo/Javamania/blob/main/gatoAdivinator.java

Comment: Si estaba pensando mas o menos asi pero el ejercicio requiere que uses todas esas constantes mi problema es que no se como rellenar los arreglos de 7 posiciones con lo que esta cargado en el deck para asi imprimir todos los 21 caracteres y es lo unico que me esta frenando ya que el menu no es algo extremadamente dificil si me podes iluminar con eso te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 1):

puedes modificar el código en caso quieras un [7][3],tu forma de devolver datos aleatorios esta bien, sin embargo, al pasarlos al arreglo deck estos se duplicaban en algunas iteraciones

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class Proyecto_2 {

    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        //Constantes para estandarizar los valores del programa
        final short Max_Tarjetas_Grupo = 7;//Tarjetas del grupo
        final short Max_Grupos = 3;//Cantidad de Grupos
        final short Max_Tarjetas = (Max_Tarjetas_Grupo*Max_Grupos);//Total de tarjetas
        final short Min_Tarjeta_Valor = 'A';//Tarjeta inicial en este caso letra A
       final short Max_Tarjeta_Valor= (char)(Max_Tarjetas+(int)('A')-1); //Tarjeta final.

  
        //Variable para generar los numeros aleatorios
            Random generador =  new Random();
            int m=0,numero,tope=Max_Tarjetas_Grupo;
        
        //Varibles que deben usarse para resolver el problema 
        char[] grupo1 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo],//7
               grupo2 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo],//7
               grupo3 = new char [Max_Tarjetas_Grupo];//7              
        char[] deck = new char [Max_Tarjetas];//21   

        deck[m]=(char)(generador.nextInt((int)Max_Tarjeta_Valor-(int)Min_Tarjeta_Valor+1)+(int)(Min_Tarjeta_Valor));
         for (m=1;m<deck.length;m++ ) {
            deck[m]=(char)(generador.nextInt((int)Max_Tarjeta_Valor-(int)Min_Tarjeta_Valor+1)+(int)(Min_Tarjeta_Valor));
             for (int n=0;n<m;n++ ) {
                 if((int)deck[m]==(int)deck[n]){
                      m--;
                  
                 }
             }
         }
             for (int j=0;j<(deck.length)/3;j++ ) {
                 grupo1[6-j]=deck[6-j];
                 grupo2[6-j]=deck[13-j];
                 grupo3[6-j]=deck[20-j];
             }
        
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grupo1));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grupo2));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grupo3));
        
      
    }
}
```

Comment: La verdad que gracias si funciona el problema es que no puedo usar las librerias de arrays porque no se dictaron ahora trate de hacerlo sin ellas todo bien pero imprime solo 14 caracteres

Comment: @Lion  La libreria array es solo para imprimir mas facil,pero si no quieres usarla puedes usar este metodo                                                                                    
public static String imprimeArreglo(char []arreglo){
String cadena="";
for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
    cadena+=String.valueOf(arreglo[i])+" ";
}return cadena;
}